# why does the PEWDIEPIE'S TUBE SIMULATOR didn't save the current game?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

When I am playing the pewdiepie's game, I already reach the level 11 of the game and suddenly I decided to restart my phone due to the laggy thing of the phone, then when I try to open it up again (the app) I didn't see the level 11 game that I played before, it starts again in the beginning. What should I do and why does this error happens?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek No.  Please stop duping everything to yours.  It should all be duped to the original.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you were logged out and the game didn't log you back in (The data is probably saved online), if you log in again you should get your data back. If you go to the "Social" tab (which is the speech bubble with a blue and pink person piece), there should be a button that says "Link accounts", I recommend trying that out. I haven't tested it myself, but that's the most probable resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you had linked the account or not. If you hadn't, then unfortunately you would be out of luck. If you had, though, then you would need to go to the Social tab (the blue one with a speech bubble) and click Link Accounts, then 'This is my new device', then Android, then yes to the prompt.